# Multiply a label by 3 and print result

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate, calculations

I would like to create a quiz for my students where the more parts I add to the question the more points it is worth. For each extra part, I want it to be 3 more points. In the following example, I would like it to say "Puzzle 1 (12 points)"

I have tried so many things and I think I have two problems that I don't know how to solve
1. on first run, \ref{last} is ?? and it does not go to 4 until second run. That can be probleme to give \MULTIPLY non-numeric argument.
2. even when \ref{last} should expand, it still seems there is problem. I do not know why. I get the error "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{calculator}

\begin{document}

\MULTIPLY{3}{\ref{last}}{\mypoints}
\section{Puzzle 1 (\mypoints~points)}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Part 1...
\item Part 2...
\item Part 3...
\item \label{last} Part 4...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a form of `\ref` that is, in LaTeX parlance, "expandable".  The `refcount` package offers the macro `\getrefnumber{<label>}` to do this.  This approach may require 2 compiler passes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{calculator}

\begin{document}

\MULTIPLY{3}{\getrefnumber{last}}{\mypoints}
\section{Puzzle 1 (\mypoints~points)}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Part 1...
\item Part 2...
\item Part 3...
\item \label{last} Part 4...
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `exam` class could be helpful here, especially if you don't always want the parts to have the same point value. The appearance of points and format of questions is quite customizable, and it keeps track of the points for you.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\qformat{Puzzle \thequestion:\ (\totalpoints\ points)\hfill}
\begin{questions}
\question
Question text
\begin{parts}
\part[3]
Part 1 \dots
\part[3]
Part 2 \dots
\part[2]
Part 3 \dots
\part[2]
Part 4 \dots
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `exam` class is quite customizable as well. For a layout similar to your original question you could do the following.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\arabic{partno}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{\thepartno.}
\pointformat{}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}
\qformat{\large\bfseries\thequestion\hspace{1em} Puzzle \thequestion\ (\totalpoints\ points)\hfill}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{parts}
\part[3]
Part 1 \dots
\part[3]
Part 2 \dots
\part[3]
Part 3 \dots
\part[3]
Part 4 \dots
\end{parts}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will look into transitioning my style to look at the exam class. It seems to be actively maintained and many features, including ones that will address by question. I would be curious if you are able to adapt your answer to match the output that I was looking for in my question. I wonder if it is easy with exam class.

Comment: @XuWang Please see my updated answer. It is easy to change the location of the points in the `exam` class (e.g., right or left margin, at end of question, etc.), but the points are shown by default. I'm sure this is so the students know exactly how many points each part is worth. For example, in your example you could have (4*3) or (4*2+2*2). Both would sum to twelve, but the breakdown would be unclear.